# ¿Cómo envío por url un slash sin afectar la ruta? PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Actualmente tengo un buscador que envía el parámetro ingresado en un `input`, este lo envía por el método `POST`. El problema es que cuando busco un producto que es por ejemplo "*ARGOLLA SOLDADA 1/2pg*" el parámetro enviado lleva un slash(`/`).

Este slash hace que no se pueda cargar ningún resultado de la búsqueda y así mismo genera un error.

He utilizador funciones de php para que omitan los signos alfanumericos, pero el resultado no es precisivo.

Les dejo el FORM.

```
<form role="search" action="{{url('articulos/')}}" class="searchform">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="palabra" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa el nombre del producto que buscas!" style="height: 35px; width:60%;"/>

        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

En la RUTA.

```
Route::get('articulos/', function(){

    /* Nota: si el argumento search está vacío regresar a la página anterior */
    if (empty(Input::get('palabra'))) return redirect()->back();

    if (empty(Input::get('sub')) && empty(Input::get('cat'))) {

        $search = str_slug(Input::get('palabra'));
        $route = "buscar/$search";

        return redirect($route);

    }     
});

Route::get("buscar/{search}", "principalController@buscar");
```

y En el Controller.

```
public function buscar($search){

  $palabra = urldecode($search);
  $categoria = "Busqueda general";

    $respuesta = vcomp_productos_web1::busqueda($palabra);
    $categorias = vcomp_productos_web1::consultarCategorias();

    if (count($respuesta) == 0) {

        return view('productos.busquedaGeneral', ['articulos' => $respuesta, 'categorias' => $categorias, 'categoria' => $categoria]);

    } else {

        return view('productos.busquedaGeneral', ['articulos' => $respuesta, 'categorias' => $categorias, 'categoria' => $categoria]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, podrías encriptar  los valores y al resibirlos los desencriptas

Comment: Lo he hecho bro, pero aún así no funciona.. no pasa del archivo route.

Comment: otra opción seria remplazarlo por un carácter x o escaparlo como codigo `%2F` esta pregunta en ingles talves te sirva https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992231/slashes-in-url-variables

Comment: 1) Las dos rutas que tenés definidas son por GET, no por POST. 2) Por qué no envías directamente el formulario a `principalController@buscar`? No veo que sentido tiene enviarlo a `articulos/` para luego hacer un `redirect`. Por otro lado, de esa forma no tendrías que `encodear`/`desencriptar` nada, simplemente envías por `POST` el input y lo pasás directamente a `::busqueda`. Si aún así no funciona, entonces el problema lo tenés en ese método.

Comment: Se ha hecho lo que dices anteriormente pero no ha habido fruto de ello.

Comment: Podrías decir que error es el que genera? Publicá el código de `::busqueda()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución aplicada para este problema fué reemplazar la función str_lug por la función urlencode que codifica todos los valores alfanumericos, posterior a ello en el controlador tuve que utilizar urldecode para decodificarlos y así obtener los valores exactos para realizar la respectiva busqueda.

```
Route::get('articulos/', function(){

/* Nota: si el argumento search está vacío regresar a la página anterior */
if (empty(Input::get('palabra'))) return redirect()->back();

if (empty(Input::get('sub')) && empty(Input::get('cat'))) {

    $route = "buscar/".urlencode(Input::get('palabra'));
}
});
```

Ya al enviar el parametro decodificado por url no me generará error ya que los slash( / ) las comas ( , ) y puntos ( . ) están codificados..

Por ultimo en el controlador los decodifiqué de la siguiente manera.

```
public function buscar($search){

$palabra = urldecode($search);

$categoria = "Busqueda general";

    $respuesta = vcomp_productos_web1::busqueda($palabra);
    $categorias = vcomp_productos_web1::consultarCategorias();

    if (count($respuesta) == 0) {

        return view('productos.busquedaGeneral', ['articulos' => $respuesta, 'categorias' => $categorias, 'categoria' => $categoria]);

    } else {

        return view('productos.busquedaGeneral', ['articulos' => $respuesta, 'categorias' => $categorias, 'categoria' => $categoria]);
    }
}
```

Comment: te añadi una respuesta que simplifica todo esto y evita tener que usar parches como en tu solucion. Espero te ayude. un saludo

Answer (score 0):

A ver hay cosas que no entiendo de tu código o que no tienen mucho sentido.

Por ejemplo no es necesario crear 2 rutas para lo que pretendes, una de las 2 esta sobrando, es poco intuitivo.

No tiene sentido pasar parámetros de un `form` como parte del cuerpo de la ruta, más aún si es una consulta de filtrado lo que estas haciendo y no controlamos lo que el cliente pueda escribir, estos deberían ir como lo que son, parámetros, y por lo tanto deberían estar en la parte de consulta de la url, es decir después del signo `?`.

En el controlador siempre devuelves la misma vista, el `if` no hace nada.

Edit: Segun veo en tu respuesta lo que haces es añadir complejidad innecesaria, es decir das un rodeo, cuando se puede hacer todo mas simple e entendible.

---

Dicho esto expongamos un ejemplo de como podría quedar.

Creamos una ruta get para mostrar los artículos, con y sin filtro, apuntando al método `@index` del controlador `ArticulosController`

```
Route::get("articulos/", "ArticulosController@index");
```

Creamos el método que manejará dicha ruta, para el ejemplo index.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
// Importamos Request
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticulosController extends Controller
{
    // inyectamos la dependencia Request
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        // Comprobamos si esiste buscar y no esta vacio el metodo filled() determina si existe y no esta vacío
        if ($request->filled('buscar')) {
            // Búsqueda CON parametros utilizamos $request->parametro para obtener el valor de buscar   
            $respuesta = \vcomp_productos_web1::busqueda($request->buscar);
        } else {
            // busqueda SIN parametros          
            $respuesta = \vcomp_productos_web1::get();
        }

        // Otra consulta sin filtros
        $categorias = \vcomp_productos_web1::consultarCategorias();
        // retornamos la vista
        return view('productos.busquedaGeneral', ['articulos' => $respuesta, 'categorias' => $categorias, 'categoria' => 'Busqueda general']);
    }
}
```

En este metodo se atenderan las peticiones de `midominio.es/articulos` (sin parametros) y otras como `midominio.es/articulos?buscar=lo/que_queramos\buscar` (con parametros), fijese que los parametros de busquedan van despues del `?` (`?buscar=lo/que_queramos\buscar`).

Por último creemos un form cualquiera que apunte a dicha ruta:

```
<form role="search" action="{{url('articulos/')}}" method="GET" class="searchform">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="buscar" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar"/>

        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

Por otro lado, ya que estas usando laravel aprobechate de las funciones y metodos que nos proporciona el framework, te hará la vida mas facil y el codigo mas legible.

Comment: Inicialmente hize esto por metodo GET y como lo expusiste anteriormente, pero la paginación no funcionaba. Cuando hacia clic para ir a la "pagina 3" del resultado de esa consulta se cargaba nuevamente esa ruta trayendome ya resultados que no coinciden con lo que yo ingresé en el input.

Comment: @RubxnMC ¿La paginación es propia hecha por ti o utilizas la de laravel? si es con laravel basta con añadir los parametros a la paginación antes de llamar al metodo `render()` con el método `appends()` para que mantenga los valores. Pero en ningun lado mostraste nada respecto de la paginación ni dijiste nada. puedes ver los metodos del paginador aquí: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html

Comment: utilicé todos los parametros de paginación que me ofrece laravel, pero aún así no funcionó.. por eso tuve que recurrir a realizar todo por metodo post.

Comment: @RubxnMC Abriste alguna pregunta al respecto para revisar como lo estabas haciendo??

Comment: No señor, solamente lo consulté con el jefe y me sugirió hacerlo con el metodo POST y funcionó perfectamente.